# How can I log everything that is written in powershell window?

Tags: powershell, logging, warnings, verbose

I am needing to create a logfile for every action that is performed by this script.

I have attempted to use redirection(>>) however, cannot get the output to actually write to the file.

```
while($true){

$FromMC = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\x\From MC" -Filter *.mpg
Write-Host "Checking '\\x\From MC' for files" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host $FromMC.count"Files Found" -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host ""
ForEach($file in $FromMC){

    try{
        Move-Item -Filter 7ST* -Path $file.Fullname -Destination "\\x\programs\7TH STREET THEATER" -Verbose -Force -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    catch{...}
Write-Host "Pausing for"$ts.Minutes"minutes..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
Write-Host "Ctrl+C to Stop"
Write-Host ""
Start-Sleep -Seconds $ts.TotalSeconds
}
```

I expect the output to be exactly as "-verbose" outputs into the shell.  Types of output: Write-Host, Verbose, Write-Warning

I feel the solution is extremely simple, and I am just overlooking it.

Comment: Write-Host is not redirected, it is used for interactions with the user on the console. Use ```Write-Output``` instead (or just don't assign the return values). And error output can be redirected through ```2>>```.

Comment: take a look at powershell auditing. that gets almost everything ... and is set at the OS level, not in any particular script. it's a group of GPO settings that can be easily controlled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To log everything that would normally be written to the console, like `-verbose` you can use `Start-Transcript` and when you are finished `Stop-Transcript`.

Example:

```
Start-Transcript -Path "C:\logs.txt"

#run code you want to capture

Stop-Transcript
```